# Text to the right of an image using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image and I want to put text on the right of the image (like sort of table or something)

I tried grid layout with `<div class="span2">`  and `<div class="span10">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 ">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3rcu77cYuBPWjgD_I1CLIQ0hoD6iArebYfA&usqp=CAU">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <h5> This is a Course Name </h5>
      <p>This my course description </p>
      <span>[Professor Name]</span>
      <span id="hours">[Total hours]</span>
      <p> Total Hours</p>
      <span id="stud-nbr">[Number Of Students]</span>
      <p> Students</p>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
      <a href="#" class="btn button-highlight">Start!</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IhebEddin/ryb4ude5/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use `d-flex` since you are using bootstrap.

Documentation: [Flex - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)

```css
.span2,
.span10 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="span2">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/sports/">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <h5> This is a Course Name </h5>
      <p>This my course description </p>
      <span>[Professor Name]</span>
      <span id="hours">[Total hours]</span>
      <p> Total Hours</p>
      <span id="stud-nbr">[Number Of Students]</span>
      <p> Students</p>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
      <a href="#" class="btn button-highlight">Start!</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Use `align-items-stretch` to make both equal height. Added `border`( and `padding`) to show that they have equal `height`

Comment: I was thinking about something to make them aligned in same div (same height of picture and text box). sorry i'm kind of new to web dev.

Comment: That really helped me , thank you for your fast replies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can try using flexbox. Use the below.

```
.row-fluid{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: I voted +1 as it is the most logical but I would have even added  class `d-flex` on this div works too and it is bootstrap 4 way

Comment: It is me, the downvoter. The reason why I downvoted is (as been said here before): d-flex already exist in Bootstrap4, which is a tag the OP used. Therefore there is no reason to adjust the bootstrap class yourself. In general, I would never advise to change the built-in bootstrap classes if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap you can make use of **media object**. Using `media`, `mr-3` and `media-body` as a minimum you can get the style you are looking for. Check out the documentation on bootstrap to see further uses [Bootstrap Media](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/media-object/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="media">
  <div class="mr-3">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3rcu77cYuBPWjgD_I1CLIQ0hoD6iArebYfA&usqp=CAU">
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5> This is a Course Name </h5>
    <p>This my course description </p>
    <span>[Professor Name]</span>
    <span id="hours">[Total hours]</span>
    <p> Total Hours</p>
    <span id="stud-nbr">[Number Of Students]</span>
    <p> Students</p>
    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn button-highlight">Start!</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated bootstrap version in link. Haven't seen `media` utility before. Thanks